# Running script in host server from my computer and shutting down my computer

Tags: server, ssh, remote-access

I'm very new to ssh and working with servers. I know how to make a connection to a server, and how to run a local script in a host server.

However I always have to have my terminal open while the script is running. The thing is that I'm about to run a script which is expected to finish in a couple of weeks. I cannot have my computer on for two weeks. How can I "send" the instruction to run my script and be able to shut down my computer while the server is running?

If this is not possible, can I copy the script to the server's hard drive and "send" the instruction to run that script, and be able to shut down my computer?

Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `screen` program.

You can ssh to your server, then create a new login session by typing:

```
screen
```

In that session, you can start off your script that will take a couple of weeks.

You can then detach from that session by typing:

```
Ctrl-a Ctrl-d
```

You can then log off your `ssh` session, and your script is still running in the detached `screen` session.

Later, you can `ssh` in to your server again and type:

```
screen -r
```

This will reattach you to the detached session from before, and you can see how your script is going. If not finished, just detach again.

Also note that if your screen session is *accidentally* detached (e.g. `ssh` stops working, or a network outage) your `screen` session will still be there and you can ssh again and `screen -r` to reattach!